# Unable to ping Active Directory Server with Domain Name

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

Domain Controller - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard

Client OS - Window Server 2003 ( Terminal Server )

I am unable to ping my Active Directory Domain Name i.e corp.abc.com. ( Please see the print-screen )

I am successfully able to nslookup & ping my DC server ip address ( Please see the print-screen )[image]

I am also attaching print-screen of IP configuration.
[image]

Can you tell me why i am unable to ping, but successfully able to resolve through nslookup command and also able to ping with DC server ip address

Comment: Does it work if you ping some other server's FQDN (DNS name)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use following command to resolve this problem.

1) net stop dnscache

2) net start dnscache

Comment: I faced with the issue several times on different machines. What is the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Ping uses the DNS Client service and I think nslookup establishes a winsock connection.  Try to stop DNS client service to see if it might help. Make sure you are trying to ping from a client that is joined with the ADC.

Use these commands to reset some of the network states:

```
As Torai suggested try to flush DNS resolver cache : ipconfig /flushdns
Reset TCP/IP stack to defaults : netsh int ip reset reset.log
Flush routing table : route /f (reboot required)
Reset WINSOCK entries to defaults : netsh winsock reset catalog
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this recently turned out to be the netbios cache was out of date.

Try flushing it using

```
nbtstat -R
```

then ping again

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757819(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Please restart Dnscache services. Go to services.msc --> Click on DNS Client and than restart.

Answer (score 0):

From the Domain controller ping domain.com
If still the issue then run below command from cmd
devmgmt.msc
uninstall the network card from the console.
Later select "Scan for hardware changes" and the network will be back again.

Regards
Sufyan.samad

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to flush your DNS. nslookup is going to the server for it, but local DNS has it cached.

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I went and turned off firewall and it worked. Usually systems with FireWall enabled do not allow pinging in certain cases.
Go to PowerShell. Type in the following.

> netsh advfirewall set allprofiles state off

The next line should be generated as

> Ok.

Try pinging your domain name now. 
Hope this helps! Thanks.

Comment: OP states that a ping by IP works.

Comment: Also disabling the firewall because you can't ping is a bit of a stretch.