# Unable to ping the domain name of an active directory

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

Domain Controller (DC) & DNS server: Windows Server 2016
Client: Windows 10

DC and DNS server are integrated in one device and it has an internal IP. An SSL-VPN is used to connect the client with the DC. I set the reverse lookup zone. I can ping the `server`'s ip `172.19.65.76`, however I cannot ping the domain name.

The output of `nslookup abc.com` is

```
Server: ****.abc.com
Address: 172.19.65.76

Name: abc.com
Address: 172.19.65.76
```

I tried `ipconfig/ dnsflush` but this did not work.

I have checked these two posts but neither worked:

1. [https://serverfault.com/questions/882178/cannot-join-domain-by-name-but-can-ping-dc-ip-and-domain-name#*=*](https://serverfault.com/questions/882178/cannot-join-domain-by-name-but-can-ping-dc-ip-and-domain-name#_=_)
2. [Unable to ping Active Directory Server with Domain Name](https://serverfault.com/questions/542878/unable-to-ping-active-directory-server-with-domain-name)

Could you please help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: Name resolution works. Why do you need to ping the name? What will that accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I cannot make the client join the domain so I ping the name to test whether the client can extract the domain name correctly or not.

Comment: Your nslookup clearly shows that the client can resolve the domain name. Ping is a red herring. Can you tell us what happens when you try to join the domain? What messages or errors do you get.